# Wordpress connection reset/meta refresh

Tags: wordpress, redirect

My site has been behaving oddly in the past week.

http://www.newsatden.co.uk

It seems something is causing a meta refresh/redirect when a user loads the page for the first time. Google Chrome returns "the connection was reset" error.

This has been causing problems with robots and preventing sites like FB, Bit.ly etc from crawling pages properly, as they often can't loads the page. The FB debugger often returns this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/strict.dtd">
<!-- <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> --><html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0.1">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<title></title>
</head>
<body><p></p></body>
</html>
```

My host suggested it was because Wordpress is forcing the domain to include "www." The Meta refresh only appears when the domain is entered without "www."

But why this would suddenly become an issue after over six months is beyond me.

Comment: Has anything happened to your .htaccess file recently? Just a guess, but I think the www rewrite is normally done by (WordPress-created) htaccess rules, and if that's broken for any reason, perhaps it resorts to a Meta refresh?

Comment: My htcaccess currently reads: 

`<Files ~ ".*\..*">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>`

That doesn't sound right?

Answer (score 0):

Try using .htaccess to force "301" redirect so browser will redirect page before hitting your meta refreshes: http://www.htaccessbasics.com/force-www-nonwww-domain/